# how to change the regex responsible for vim's "current word" search

Tags: vim

Is there any way to modify the "current word" search (asterisk) settings so it includes certain characters in its definition of "word".

For example, I have a lot of CSS code where there is a dash character in the class names. So, if I have a class named "blue-text" and the cursor is positioned on "blue" and I hit asterisk, it will search for "blue" while I want it to search for "blue-text". It would be nice if I can use a custom regex for the asterisk search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's the `iskeyword` option. It has all characters to take into account for searches and patterns, and by default the dash character is not included, but you can fix it adding it, like:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

---

**UPDATE** with the comment of [Ingo Karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat):

To use it only for `css` files, edit `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim` and add:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

so it will not affect when you work with other languages.

Comment: And to apply this to CSS only, but this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim`, and use `:setlocal`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Thanks. I've improved the answer with your info.